# Unicode Library - Where to Find One (NEW FOCUS: Unicode in XSL-FO)

Tags: unicode, xsl-fo

EDIT: I am no longer asking for a Unicode Library.  Not only has one been linked, but the origial question was inappropriate to ask, as mentioned below.  This question is now focused on how to implement unicode in XSL-FO.

My primary question now is what steps are required in implementing the unicode.  I already have the necessary unicode character references, but I understand that the proper 'font' needs to be selected as well, and am led to believe there are other steps that need to be taken in order to implement it in my XSL-FO document.

Comment: Here is a Unicode library (or rather, set of libraries): http://site.icu-project.org/. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: This question is inappropriate for StackOverflow. Google and Bing both specialize in searching the web for things and returning links to the search results. SO is not a link collection or referral service. There are Meta posts [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/172661) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/172661) that explain the reasons.

Comment: I apologize for the inappropriate question.  I wasn't aware of that rule/reasoning.  

I will edit this question to make it more appropriate for discussion.

Comment: @user2188082, you shouldn't try to make the question "appropriate for discussion". SO is not a discussion forum, it is a Question & Answer site. Please try to ask *specific* questions that can be answered based on facts and references. What exactly is the problem? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Particular languages are giving me trouble. In particular, Korean, Chinese, and Russian.  When trying to use unicode for this language, the characters display as # symbols in my PDF.  I've tried numerous different fields for my font-type tags, and none of them seem to work.  I'm stuck using IE 6 as my browser too, if that makes any difference.

Comment: OK, so this might boil down to font problems. Then please **show us** what you have tried. Provide details. How can I (or anyone else) reproduce the problem? What FO processor do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "write foreign characters"?  An XSL-FO file is just an XML file, so you can use any Unicode reference to figure out the character number and then an XML numeric character reference to include it.

For example, the Unicode hex for the Euro symbol € is U+20ac, so in XML (XSL-FO) that would be &#x20ac;

Comment: Like I said in the edit above, I'm specifically trying to change my wordml file into a pdf with XSL-Fo code. So, if I understand correctly, the Unicode in my wordML should be compatable with XSL-FO?

Also, in terms of finding a decent library of Unicode at all...I've had basically no luck in such an endeavor.  Being able to use my old file as a reference would be good for me, but wouldn't solve the larger question of where to find a good library for others.

Comment: Unicode is standardized, and XML is based on Unicode.  If your wordML is using UTF-8 or UTF-16, and not one of the Windows custom encodings, then Unicode is Unicode.  If you are using one of the custom encodings, say Windows-1252, then your question is incorrect as Unicode is not being used.  But if you are using UTF-8 or UTF-16, then the Unicode characters and encodings are the same as used in XSL-FO.  Anyway, if your XSLT processor supports Windows-1252, then transformation should be straightforward.  And what do you mean by "a library"?  A code library?  A library for doing what?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a same kind of problem. The problem with unicode characters is hardcoded in the FONET.DLL. In the class `TrueTypeFont` method `MapCharacter` is written as:

```
public override ushort MapCharacter(char c) 
{
    if (c > Byte.MaxValue) 
        return (ushort) FirstChar;
    return mapping.MapCharacter(c);
}
```

So any character with a value greater than 255 will be "ignored". I downloaded the sources (from https://fonet.codeplex.com/) and modified the method to:

```
public override ushort MapCharacter(char c) 
{
    return mapping.MapCharacter(c);
}
```

Using this library with this new method, the euro-symbol magically became visible!